# How to know the orientation of the tip of the arrow with fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

***This is the code that creates the arrow:***

I need to detect the orientation where the arrow is pointing both when starting or doing some transformation of the arrow

```
var Arrow = Fabric.util.createClass(Fabric.Line, Fabric.Observable, {
    type: 'arrow',
    positionArrow: 'rt',

    initialize: function (points, options) {
        this.callSuper('initialize', points, options);
        this.on('modified', function() {
            console.log(this.toObject())
        });
    },

    _render: function(ctx, noTransform) {
        this._setStrokeStyles(ctx);
        this._drawArrowHead(ctx);
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx, noTransform);
    },

    _drawArrowHead: function(ctx) {
        var p = this.calcLinePoints();
        var rot = Math.atan2(p.y2, p.x2);

        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(p.x1, p.y1);
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.rotate(rot);
        ctx.lineTo(15, 7);
        ctx.lineTo(3, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(15, -7);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
    },

     _setStrokeStyles: function(ctx) {
         if (this.stroke) {
             ctx.lineWidth = this.strokeWidth;
             ctx.lineCap = this.strokeLineCap;
             ctx.lineJoin = this.strokeLineJoin;
             ctx.miterLimit = this.strokeMiterLimit;
             ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke.toLive ? this.stroke.toLive(ctx) : this.stroke;
         }
     }
});
```

I have added an observer when the object is transformed in the initialization, but I have found the way to know in which position the arrow is pointing.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48316643/3551786)

Answer (score 0):

If you know how much you should rotate the canvas to draw an arrowHead, you should also be able to get the full angle reusing that code and adding the object angle.

```js
fabric.Arrow = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Line, {
    type: 'arrow',
    positionArrow: 'rt',

    initialize: function (points, options) {
        this.callSuper('initialize', points, options);
        this.on('modified', function() {
          var p = this.calcLinePoints();
          var rot = Math.atan2(p.y2, p.x2);
          var rotDeg = fabric.util.radiansToDegrees(rot);
          console.log(this.angle + rotDeg)
        });
    },

    _render: function(ctx) {
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
        this._setStrokeStyles(ctx);
        this._drawArrowHead(ctx);
    },

    _drawArrowHead: function(ctx) {
        var p = this.calcLinePoints();
        var rot = Math.atan2(p.y2, p.x2);

        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(p.x1, p.y1);
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.rotate(rot);
        ctx.lineTo(15, 7);
        ctx.lineTo(3, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(15, -7);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
    },

     _setStrokeStyles: function(ctx) {
         if (this.stroke) {
             ctx.lineWidth = this.strokeWidth;
             ctx.lineCap = this.strokeLineCap;
             ctx.lineJoin = this.strokeLineJoin;
             ctx.miterLimit = this.strokeMiterLimit;
             ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke.toLive ? this.stroke.toLive(ctx) : this.stroke;
         }
     }
});

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var arrow = new fabric.Arrow([10,10, 70,20]);
canvas.add(arrow);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300" ></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks, although the angle always returns value of 0, I have been able to obtain it with the following function:

    var matrix = this.calcTransformMatrix (),
    options = Fabric.util.qrDecompose (matrix);
    console.log (optionsObject.angle);

but the value is not yet exact to know the direction of the arrow head.

Comment: my fiddle does not return 0. it returns you an agle

Comment: you have the link to your fiddle?

Comment: is here on the answer, press run snippet and look in the console on object modified